# SQL Multi Condition query with Nulls Values entered in search give no results

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server

net web app with search page I have 3 text boxes to do filtered search if I entered text in all text boxes the result will show but when I entered text in only one text box the result not showing my question is how can I to be able to search data if I entered text in only one text box or two or all of the text boxes and my query is showing below:

```
SELECT Emp_NUM, Full_name, Mother_Name, Date_of_Birth, Province_of_birth, Job
FROM  [Emp Main Table]
WHERE (Full_name LIKE '%' + @Full_name + '%' OR Full_name IS NULL) AND 
(Mother_Name LIKE '%' + @Mother_Name + '%' OR Mother_Name IS NULL) AND 
(Date_of_Birth LIKE '%' + @Date_of_Birth + '%' OR Date_of_Birth IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like that:

```
SELECT [Emp_NUM]
,[Full_name]
,[Mother_Name]
,[Date_of_Birth]
,[Province_of_birth]
,[Job] 
FROM [Emp Main Table] 
WHERE ([Full_name] LIKE '%'+@Full_name+'%' OR RTRIM(COALESCE(@Full_name,''))='')
AND ([Mother_Name] LIKE '%'+@Mother_Name+'%' OR RTRIM(COALESCE(@Mother_Name,''))='')
AND ([Date_of_Birth] LIKE '%'+@Date_of_Birth+'%' OR RTRIM(COALESCE(@Date_of_Birth,''))='')
```

Comment: yes that's right I forget to put it like that in here ?

Comment: Did you notice @Full_name IS NULL instead of Full_name IS NULL? You have to examine does an empty textbox returns NULL - it doesn't have to.

Comment: it's my bad thank u for ur help bro with my best wishes

Comment: I have updated the code with that what Anand showed below. It will tackle with spaces in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
rtrim(coalesce(@Full_name, '')) = ''
```

Instead of:

```
@Full_name is null
```

For checking against empty or blank values

Comment: Why @Anand can you explain

Comment: If user entry is a space, for example, that code would eliminate it because a space is not null